# WPF DataGrid build from List<SomeInterface> using AutoGenerateColumns

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I'm trying to load data to DataGrid from a generic list.

the relevant code:

XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid  DataContext="{Binding Lines}"
               ItemsSource="{Binding}"
               AutoGenerateColumns="True">
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

C#:

```
 public IList<IReportLine> Lines { get; set; }
 public interface IReportLine {}
 public class ReportLine : IReportLine
 {
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
 }
```

It seems that the columns are taken from the type IReportLine - so I'm getting an empty DataGrid.

Of course, if I'm changing IReportLine definition to:

```
public interface IReportLine
{
    string A { get; set; }
    string B { get; set; }
}
```

it works perfectly, but i can't do that because every class that implement IReportLine has different Properties.

What can I do in order to make the columns be generated from the dynamic type of IReportLine?
Or have any other idea to solve my problem?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

The interface holding the Lines property and the class implementing the interface(one of many):

```
    interface IReport
    {
       string Header { get; set; }
       IList<IReportLine> Lines { get; set; }
    }
    public class Report : IReport
    {
       public string Header
       {
           get;
           set;
       }
       public IList<IReportLine> Lines
       {
           get;
           set;
       }
    }
```

The DataContext of the DataGrid is IReport object.

So I can't Change

```
public IList<IReportLine> Lines { get; set; }
```

to

```
public IList<ReportLine> Lines { get; set; }
```

Comment: How can you expect the compiler to know about properties other than IReportLine if that is all you can expose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of defining members in interface, make the list to be more verbose. You gotta tell dataGrid at least some specific type so that it can look for properties in it.

Change

```
public IList<IReportLine> Lines { get; set; }
```

to

```
public IList<ReportLine> Lines { get; set; }
```

---

**UPDATE**

Like I mentioned above, if you want columns to be auto generated, you gotta supply some specific type.

Consider scenario where you have another class say `AnotherReportLine` implementing `IReportLine`:

```
public class AnotherReportLine : IReportLine
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }
}
```

Now, you can add both class instances in `Lines` collection like this:

```
 Lines = new List<IReportLine>();
 Lines.Add(new ReportLine() { A = "A1", B = "B1" });
 Lines.Add(new AnotherReportLine() { A = "A1", B = "B1", C = "C1" });
```

What should be the columns list now?

**`A | B`** OR **`A | B | C`**.
*WPF engine cannot infer that without your help*.

That brings you down to three possible ways:

- Move properties to interface.
- Make the list of more specific type.
- Last set `AutoGenerateColumns` to `False` and provide your own list of columns you want to show.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. but i can't do that. i will update the post adding some code.

Comment: Thanks! you are right. about the third option, there is a way in XAML that i can bind the columns to be different according to the Object of the list? and another question(not related to the first one): if i set the ContentTemplate in TabControl to be a UserControl that i created, why when i switching tabs the content of the tabitem is not changed? thanks!

Comment: For first question, I would suggest to have `ContentControl` and have different templates based on `Content`. For second question, I would need some code to look at. Please post separate question with relevant code needed for that.

Comment: About the first answer, can you give me a link with simple example? About the second answer, thanks i will do that!

Comment: Refer to [ContentTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contenttemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx). I was referring to have two separate instances of dataGrid for each type and based on type simply switch the dataGrid to be shown inside Contentcontrol.