# WPF Type resolving of dynamic/derived Types with DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Here is what I do:
1. I create a Type **T1** and implement an interface **I1**
2. I use a DataGrid with Autogenerated Columns and a `List<I1>` of as the Itemssource.
The Grid generates all columns for *I1*, but **not** for **T1**!
If I use `List<object>` as the Type for the Item source, I get all the properties.
Accessing Properties with *Bindings* of a T1 while exposing it as I1 works like expected. Also adding columns aiming for T1 Properties works fine.

It seems inheritance confuses the typesystem of WPF (or is it just the Grid there?)
Any Suggestions?

**EDIT:** The issue is connected to the way the DataGrid AutoGenerates Columns. It's a little weird and this is what I have to modify.
I casted a close vote, just to make this post appear on searches, but there is basicly no answer since its a DataGrid Issue.

Comment: Any code to show?

Comment: Nope, it is a simple as I said.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the columns to be auto-generated you should set the ItemsSource to an `List<T1>`. This makes perfect sense. Imagine that you have several types that implements the `I1` interface, how should the runtime be able to figure out what columns to generate then?

The `List<I1>` may for example contain an instance of a type `U1` that has 10 public properties and another instance of a type `V1` that has 20 public properties.

Please refer to the answer to the following similar question for more information.

[WPF DataGrid build from List<SomeInterface> using AutoGenerateColumns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21969127/wpf-datagrid-build-from-listsomeinterface-using-autogeneratecolumns)

Comment: This is corrent, when you mix up types in collections, which is pretty uncommon in modern OOP - at least when it comes to displaying the details in a grid.

Comment: Uncommon or not, the DataGrid cannot guess what columns you want to be auto-generated unless you specify the columns or the concrete type with the public properies. As mentioned, this makes perfect sense. Defining a List<I1> that will only ever contain objects of type T1 makes less sense. So you should just change the type of the source collection.

Comment: This is not possible at design time, as the types are generated. However I fixed the Datagrid with about 10 Lines of code to work as it makes more sence.

Comment: Further: exposing a more precise type is usally an indication for an mvvm pattern break... So thanks for the Input, my Issue is solved.